# How do I pass build arguments to my .NET Unit Tests

Tags: .net, variables, tfs, build

I have a need to pass custom build settings down to the unit tests. I know I can use System.EnvironmentVariable in the code. I'm wondering how I can add a parameter to the TFS build definition and have that be readable as an env parameter in the code. It has to be specified in the build definition by our release engineer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to use a [preprocessor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) to conditionally execute some code.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod () 
{
    bool buildArgumentIsSet = false;

    #if MY_BUILD_ARGUMENT
        buildArgumentIsSet = true
    #endif

    Assert.IsFalse(
        buildArgumentIsSet, 
        "The evil release engineer set the build argument.");        
}
```

Your release engineer can then compile with the [/define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) argument, e.g

```
/define:MY_BUILD_ARGUMENT
```

Comment: I'm afraid we have a one-build-per-env policy for all deployments for consistency and no chance of differences. We ended up adding a custom property to the Build Definition that causes a prop file to be generated so our config API can detect/use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it in the app.config and use `ConfigurationManager` to read it?

Comment: We make heavy use of .NET config already, and the problem was being able to override it on a per release branch basis. We ended up using Build Defintion custom properties, which was simple clean